# Completely remove the changes of a specific file from the history

Tags: git

I created a branch, did multiple commits and pushed the changes to a remote repository:

```
git checkout -b my-feature
git commit -m "1"
git commit -m "2"
git commit -m "3"
git commit -m "4"
git commit -m "5"
```

in 3-rd commit I changed two files:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only <hash3> -r
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

Is there a way to remove `file1.txt` changes, but keep `file2.txt` changes?

Not by doing

```
git checkout origin/origial_branch file1.txt
git commit -a -m "undoing file1.txt changes"
```

but completely removing `file1.txt` changes from the history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do interactive rebase on commit before the one you would like to modify, set it for edit at the commit you would like to modify, amend that commit and proceed with rebase resolving any conflicts that can emerge. After that, force push your change to the remote repo.

See more info on how to achieve that in the [official documentation, section Rewriting history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

Say we have history like this:

```
$ git log
commit c4e983a7f506f71e01d2e1e4cddf2f768e2c2548 (HEAD -> main)
Author: REDACTED
Date:   REDACTED

    3

commit 3e616c11fa1ce71157e4b654e4e3742f97c6e0e6
Author: REDACTED
Date:   REDACTED

    2

commit 7655a6d373c26db5d30086a6e7e23e755c960924
Author: REDACTED
Date:   REDACTED

    1
```

Second commit does change two files:

```
t$ git show 3e616c11fa1ce71157e4b654e4e3742f97c6e0e6
commit 3e616c11fa1ce71157e4b654e4e3742f97c6e0e6
Author: REDACTED
Date:   REDACTED

    2

diff --git a/file1.txt b/file1.txt
index e69de29..d00491f 100644
--- a/file1.txt
+++ b/file1.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+1
diff --git a/file2.txt b/file2.txt
index e69de29..0cfbf08 100644
--- a/file2.txt
+++ b/file2.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+2
```

Let us remove the change in `file2.txt` in the second commit by rebasing our branch on top of the commit before our target commit to be modified:

```
git rebase -i 7655a6d373c26db5d30086a6e7e23e755c960924
```

We are presented with this:

```
pick 3e616c1 2
pick c4e983a 3

# Rebase 7655a6d..c4e983a onto 7655a6d (2 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup [-C | -c] <commit> = like "squash" but keep only the previous
#                    commit's log message, unless -C is used, in which case
#                    keep only this commit's message; -c is same as -C but
#                    opens the editor
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
# .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
# .       specified); use -c <commit> to reword the commit message
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

Change it to this

```
e 3e616c1 2
pick c4e983a 3
```

Save and quit. Now we are at the point after comiting the second change. Just pick previous version:

```
git checkout 7655a6d373c26db5d30086a6e7e23e755c960924 file2.txt
```

amend the commit:

```
git commit --amend
```

and continue:

```
git rebase --continue
```

Now we have conflict:

```
 git status 
interactive rebase in progress; onto 7655a6d
Last commands done (2 commands done):
   edit 3e616c1 2
   pick c4e983a 3
No commands remaining.
You are currently rebasing branch 'main' on '7655a6d'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   file1.txt

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
    both modified:   file2.txt
```

Fix that, add it to mark resolution and continue:

```
$ nano file2.txt 
$ git add file2.txt 
$ git rebase --continue
```

Done:

```
$ git log
commit 2e1fd6f9f90a6d9cac7f618962246152ad9c63e6 (HEAD -> main)
Author: REDACTED
Date:   REDACTED

    3

commit 4b2fa59148dc79dd9c3be70c54efebf453d6f125
Author: REDACTED
Date:   REDACTED

    2

commit 7655a6d373c26db5d30086a6e7e23e755c960924
Author: REDACTED
Date:   REDACTED

    1
$  git show 4b2fa59148dc79dd9c3be70c54efebf453d6f125
commit 4b2fa59148dc79dd9c3be70c54efebf453d6f125
Author: REDACTED
Date:   REDACTED

    2

diff --git a/file1.txt b/file1.txt
index e69de29..d00491f 100644
--- a/file1.txt
+++ b/file1.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+1
```

If you pushed the previous version to remote repo, also force push your current version:

```
git push -f
```

Comment: Oh, its wired... what are the commands?

Comment: It's pretty accurate _but_ I agree with @AlexeyStarinsky that the recipe should be complete, including the commands to amend the file he is talking about.

Comment: Fixed now by adding an example.